# Same comments & likes of the Facebook fan page & the actual web page

Tags: facebook, comments

Is it possible to have the same comments and like count on your Facebook fan page and on the actual web page (using the comment box/like button)?

Our current setup is:

- Each entry on our web site has a comment box and like button
- The data-href parameter of both the comment box and like button are set to the web page URL
- We auto-post each new entry of our web site to the Facebook fan page using the Graph API

The problem is that the post on the Facebook fan page is not "connected" to the web page, in the sense that likes on the fan page do not show up on the web page and vise versa. Even worse is that the comments are not synced: comments left on the comments box on the web page do not show up as comments on the fan page, and vise versa.

Is there any way to fix this? Or is this done on purpose and will Facebook always keep the streams separate?